# Considering buying a new computer, how much of blender is CPU related vs GPU related?

Tags: gpu, osx

I'll admit, I know nothing about Blender. Hadn't even heard the name until last week.
A client of mine is looking to replace a 2010 Mac Pro with something more recent.

I told them that I'd do some research to determine where the 'sweet spot' in price/performance was on Apple's current Mac Pro offerings.

So, my question is.
How much of blender work is CPU-related, and how much is GPU related? Where do you think the best price/performance ratio lies?  Should I prioritize spending on the CPU, the GPU or look for a balance?  The six-core/D500 GPU is my current plan, but I'm willing to be persuaded.

Comment: Because it is a hardware question

Comment: One thing that likely won't be mentioned on any of those pages is that AMD has recently assigned a couple of engineers to help convert Cycles into smaller kernels so it can work  well with OpenCL/ATI and not just nVidia cards so all the GPU advice that is going around may not be be very relevant soon.